# Determine partition number of a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to determine at run time, the number of partitions a particular table has on SQL Server. I know how to query the *sys.partitions* table to manually inspect that, but I need to do it during runtime (a simple IF statement would suffice).

The scenario I have is that multiple tables were partitioned with the same strategy, using round robin to send data to a partition, and truncate the next (modulo operation), but now this strategy will be configurable on our system:

1. A user will be able to determine partitions they want.
2. System will create the table if it doesn't exist with this strategy.
3. Truncate operation on the background will clean the "oldest" partition (i.e. the one at the right of the current one).

Problem with this, is that user might mess up on their config deployment afterwards, and TRUNCATE on a different partition if the argument for the modulo operation doesn't match the oneused to partition initial table. **I'd like to detect this condition, and avoid it.**

So something like this would be ideal:

```
IF {tableName}.partitions == {expectedPartitions} THEN
   TRUNCATE {tableName} WITH (PARTITIONS({partitionToRemove}))
END
```

Any way to do this with pure (T)SQL?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14996

Comment: I don't understand... " I know how to query the sys.partitions table to manually inspect that"   ...so exactly what is it you don't know how to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can count them:

```
select count(*)
from sys.partitions
where object_id = object_id(@YourTableNameHere)
```

This is a scalar subquery that can be used in an `if`.

Comment: I think MAX would be better, because of partitions on indices. But yeah, this helps.